# Trying to concat variables values in variable names JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am new to jsp.I have a scenario where i have to loop some list and take the loop index ,apend it to another iteration's variable and get the value and set it to an elements id from which i can do some javascript functions.But when i am trying to acheive it i get the below error

### Error

```
According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute varStatus does not accept any expressions
```

My code is given below :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!-- Some codes in between  -->
<c:forEach var="myItemsList" items="${myItemsList}" varStatus="loop">
    <c:forEach var="myItemsList1"
        items="${myItemsList1}"
        varStatus="loopItr${loop.index}"> <!-- I need the variable like loopItr1 or loopItr2 -->
            <div class="myClass${loop.index}" id="myDetailsBlock_${(loopItr+loop.index).count+1}">
            <!-- SOME OF MY CODE HERE -->
        </div>
    </c:forEach>

</c:forEach>
```

I am pretty sure i am missing some syntax.Kindly help me out how to acheive this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one things to consider

1. You cannot specify an expression in `varStatus`, it should be a String literal.
2. `count` mention here `id="myDetailsBlock_${(loopItr+loop.index).count+1}"` doesn't exist.

I would suggest to rethink your solution. If you are trying to count some thing you can create your own variable using `<c:set` and increment the way you like.